# Masheches Yuma or Yoma?

Tags: names, pronunciation, masechet-yoma

I remember hearing Rabbeim call the mashechta "Yuma", but shouldn't it be called "Yoma", which I have also heard?

I know mashechta Beitzah is sometimes called "Beiah" based off the Magen Avraham or because of a halachic mistake; is there something similar by Yoma too?

Comment: Not pronounced Beiah. Cf: piyyut composed by the Ra"Ch (IIRC), found in the margin of most editions of gemara.

Comment: @AdamMosheh That just means _he_ didn't pronounce it that way (or that he was bad at writing poetry).

Comment: See Magen Avraham 156

Comment: Analysis of the topic on [daf-yomi.com](https://daf-yomi.com/Data/UploadedFiles/DY_Item/24565-sFile.doc) (doc file)

Answer (score 2):

Yoma. (However, the Jastrow’s vocalization is not all-authoritative, neither is תרגום אונקלוס for Babylonian Aramaic vowels).
As far as I know, the vowel חולם in Hebrew often becomes a קמץ in Aramaic, and when it doesn’t, it remains a חולם, unless it geminates, in which case it becomes a קובוץ which is spelled מלא ו׳. Since the מ׳ doesn’t geminate, as corroborated by אונקלוס, the vowel is חולם.
Moreover, even the people that mispronounce it as “Yuma” will agree in phrases like ספיקא דיומא that it’s pronounced “Yoma”.

Answer (score 1):

*[Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D_%C2%B2?lang=he)* vocalizes it as יוֹמָא, as in Unkolos, Bereshis 39:11:

> הֲוָה כְּיוֹמָא הָדֵין וְעָאל לְבֵיתָא לְמִבְדַק בִּכְתָבֵי חוּשְׁבָּנֵיהּ וְלֵית אֲנָשׁ מֵאֲנָשֵׁי בֵיתָא תַּמָּן בְּבֵיתָא׃

[And as for the discrepancy in pronunciation...](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/discuss_daf.php?gid=6&sid=20&daf=0&n=1)

> Our spelling is based on the Targum for the Hebrew "Yom," day, everywhere that it appears (e.g. Bereishis 1:5; 6:5, etc. I'm not sure why it became Yeshivishly accepted to call it Yuma. I don't know that the Targum ever uses "Yuma" in any context. If you find differently, please let me know. In general, the Targum just adds an Alef to the end without changing the pronunciation: Tzom/Tzoma, Rok/Roka etc.

Comment: The second link no longer works. Can you recall who said that?

Comment: @SethJ, No,  But perhaps it stands on its own..