# Does Changing "Beitza" to "Beiah" Really Acoomplish Anything?

Tags: talmud-gemara, language, yeshiva-school, tractate-beitza

There are legitimate sources that talk about calling masechet "Beitza" by the name "Beiah" because the Hebrew word "beitza" can also refer to a testicle. See [answers here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85174/is-the-shiur-called-a-kbeiah-or-a-kbeitzah) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125752/changing-beitza-to-beia). However, this change actually seems counterproductive. First, the Aramaic word "beiah" can have the same alternative meaning in Aramaic. See Chullin 93a. Second, the change seems to draw more attention to the issue. I do not see people associate the word "beitza" out of context with anatomy during learning *except* when talking about why the masechta is often called beiah and not beitza. It seems to create a [Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect). Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33303/masheches-yuma-or-yoma

Comment: @rosends I don't see how that answers it other than a passing reference to beiah vs. beia?

Comment: Language evolves. I would assume there was a stronger association when the custom developed. Btw, the first two links are the same.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel. I fixed the links. It's possible that such usage was more common among the early acharonim but I'd like to see some evidence of that. The iyei Hayam and Tiferet Israel both thought there was no reason to avoid using a perfectly good biblical word for egg.

Comment: @Avraham I didn't say it answered it but the answer suggests that we pronounce it beiah for another reason.

Comment: @rosends I see thank you. What is the other reason? I'm afraid I'm not following. The Q says something about "a halachic mistake" and then a few comments mention Rabbeinu Chananel's rhyme, which pronounces it beitza not beiah.